# Limit total size of multiple databases in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a way of limiting the total size a defined set of databases can grow to.

Take a case where you have a group of lets say 10 databases and I'd like to ensure that the combined size used by these dabases does not exceed 20GB. Distribution of data within these databases is neither even nor known to the DBA, so there is no sensible way of pre-configuring database size limits.

**Update 1:** To elaborate the scenario: The "groups" are used independently by differnt divisions. They each know the limit and it is their own responsibility to stay below this limit, otherwise databases will not be available any more.

It is my intention to have a "hard limit" per group which - in case it it reached - will forcefully prevent increasing the size, even if this means database changes or even reading from the databases is no longer possible.

An even distribution of DB limits is not feasible as the DBA does not know where the majority of data will be placed.

As detailed in the comments it is certainly a possibility to create seperate block devices per group (e.g. VHDs), but this would introduce a certain administrative overhead that I hoped to prevent.

Comment: That's rather bad and dangerous idea. But even tho, are You talking about datafiles? Datafiles with log files (for databases in `FULL RECOVERY` mode)?

Comment: You can limit the growth of individual databases by restricting it not to grow using the - uncheck [enable autogrowth] in the database properties

Comment: Create a VDI of fixed size, add that as drive to OS and  locate your database the the drive. Enjoy..... :)

Comment: @MarcinS our scenario it makes perfect sense. Actually it will apply to both, data an log files, independant of recovery mode. If you care to elaborate your concerns in a seperate answer I'll provide details why it makes sense :)

Comment: @RajeshRanjan: this is actually my "last restort" solution, but it will be relativley complex because there will be a dozen or more of these groups. I'd prefer to have something that is handeled by SQL itself if possible

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a way to do this; at best you could poll the default trace and have it *react* when an autogrow event pushes a group close to or over the limit, and then send an alert, disable autogrow for the databases, etc. It would be much easier to just divide the quota by the number of databases, and limit the autogrow of each database to its portion.

Comment: What would be your actions once the limit is reached? I would think that based on your description, you would start with an even distribution of space amongst all databases.  You can monitor actual growth rate of the databases and adjust their size parameters.  Let's say database A grows faster than the others,  you would reduce the size and auto-increment values of the others in benefit of db A, etc.  But, what would you do once the 20 GB is closed to be reached?

Comment: @David see the edit above. Once the 20GB is reached the same should happen to this specific group that happens if you run a SQL server and let the databases or log files fill all available space - just without affecting other groups.

Comment: What about just putting each group into its own folder in Windows, and using Windows to enforce a quota on the folder size?\

Comment: @leepfrog, based on your edit I favor Aaron Bertrand's proposed solution.

Comment: @AaronBertrand this is indeed something I've also thought about. However I did not find any information if this is actually supported. I know that quotas are normally transparent to the application, but it would be nice to have that written somewhere.

Comment: You want SQL Server to document how it works with Windows folder quotas?